# how to solve Laravel 6.0 error upload file

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to input some data to database
i cant input some data to database because i got that error
but i can login with multi auth in my project

and i got some error
[image]

how i can solve this error?

**controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jurusan;
use Auth;
class AdminActionsController extends Controller
{
    public function addjurusan(Request $request)
    {

        $jurusan = new Jurusan();
        $jurusan->nama_jurusan=$request->nama;
        $file=$request->file('fotohimpunan');
        if (!$file) {
            return redirect()->route('in.jurusan')->with('alert','foto harus diisi!');
        }
        $file_name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path=public_path('/img');
        $file->move($path,$file_name);
        $jurusan->fotohimpunan='public/img/'.$file_name;
        $jurusan->status='disable';
        // dd($jurusan);
        $jurusan->save();


        return redirect()->route('in.jurusan');
    }
}
```

**guard**

```
<?php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    // Guard
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'panitia' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'panitia',
        ],
        'panitia-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'panitia',
        ],
        'mahasiswa' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'mahasiswa',
        ],
        'mahasiswa-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'mahasiswa',
        ],

    ],
    //  Providers
    'providers' => [
        'panitia' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Panitia::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'mahasiswa' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Mahasiswa::class,
        ],

    ],
    // Password
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

how i can solve my problems please help me
i can login with multi auth but if i try to input some data i got that error

Comment: what middleware is assigned to the route that points to your `addjurusan` method?

Comment: Route::get('inputjurusan', 'AdminActionsController@addjurusan')->name('input.jurusan')
 ->middleware('auth:admin');

Comment: is this the default `auth` middleware? and also do a `php artisan route:list --name=input.jurusan` and see if it has more than just `auth:admin` assigned to it

Comment: web,auth:admin middleware in the routelist

Comment: thanks, can you provide the rest of the stacktrace

Comment: okay thankyou i got solve my problem, that error because the method in route is get and i change to post that was work to solve this problem

Comment: do you have your own custom error pages? are you trying to use auth in them or the layout?

Comment: glad you found the issue ... good luck with your project :)

Comment: okay thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `users` provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'panitia' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Panitia::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'mahasiswa' => [
      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\Mahasiswa::class,
    ],

],
```

The `web` guard is set to use a provider named `users`:

```
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

You need to adjust that to use a `provider` you have registered, or add a `users` provider.

Are you intending to be using the `web` guard for which ever route you are hitting and getting the error? It is possible you intend to use a different guard completely.

Comment: well that is why though, there is no `users` provider and the `web` guard is setup to use that provider

Comment: is your config cached? `php artisan config:clear` just to be sure

Comment: if you don't plan on using the `web` guard I would not have it set as the default