# Error Multy Auth Laravel 6, i can login, but i can't access my home

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 6, I make multiple logins, my multi logins are running, but after logging out, I get an error like this on my welcome page

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct()
>   must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null
>   given, called in
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\alkit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php
>   on line 125

auth.php

```
<?php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    // Guard
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'camp' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'camp',
        ],
        'camp-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'camp',
        ],
        'user' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'user',
        ],
        'user-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
    ],
    //  Providers
    'providers' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'camp' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Camp::class,
        ],
    ],
    // Password
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('index');
});

// hanya untuk tamu yg belum auth
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@getLogin')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@postLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');;

Route::get('/admin', function() {
  return view('admin');
})->middleware('auth:admin');

Route::get('/user', function() {
  return view('user');
})->middleware('auth:user');

Route::get('/camp', function() {
  return view('camp');
})->middleware('auth:camp');
```

LoginCobtroller.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Admin;
use App\User;
use App\Camp;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    }
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
      // Validate the form data

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
      // Attempt to log the user in
      // Passwordnya pake bcrypt
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        } else if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/user');
        } else if (Auth::guard('camp')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/camp');
        }

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        } else if (Auth::guard('user')->check()) {
            Auth::guard('user')->logout();
        } else if (Auth::guard('camp')->check()) {
            Auth::guard('camp')->logout();
        }
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The provider is named wrong. You should use like this

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'camps' => [
      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\Camp::class,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `web` guards configuration to use your adjusted `user` provider ... by default it wants to use a provider named `users` which you do not have.

```
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'user',
],
```

If you are not going to be using the `web` guard, you should **not** have it set as the default. The `passwords` section is an issue since the only configuration you have there is set to use the `users` provider, which you do not have.

Similarly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58896116/2109233

Also:

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@getLogin')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

Since you have not specified a guard to `guest` it will use the default guard which is `web`. So everyone who isn't logged in via the `web` guard can reach this route.

---

Having said all of that ... it is probably easier to just change the `user` provider to be named `users` and adjust your `user` and `user-api` guards to use the `users` provider.